# mvc google map in bootstrap partial view modal does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3, bootstrap-modal

Iam doing an MVC Bootstrap Google Map V3 application.

When user enter a Full Address it is shown in a `Google Map`. If the div when it is shown is in a `Partial View`. It looks fine.

But, when that Partial View is in a `Bootstrap` Modal View. It does not show anything.

This is the case when it Works..

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var geocoder;
    var map;
    var address = "Full Address ";
    function initialize() {
     
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: latlng,
     //       mapTypeControl: true,
         //   mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
       //     navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), myOptions);
        if (geocoder) {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                            { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                                size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                            });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            map: map, 
                            title:address
                        }); 
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        });

                    } else {
                        alert("No results found");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
 
    }


</script>

<div style="width: 600px; height:400px">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_ShowMap.cshtml")
  
</div>
```

this is the call to my Partial View

[image]

My partial View in this case is simple

[image]

The case that does not work is like this.

I add this line at bootom of JavaScript function...

```
 $("#myModalMapa").modal();
```

HTML Div is like this.

[image]

And my partial view looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I sow in differents questions, I made same changes to my scripts

```html
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myModalMapa').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                var currentCenter = map.getCenter();  // Get current center before resizing
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(currentCenter); // Re-set previous center
            });
        });
```